# Gvim and Unicode indic characters

Tags: gvim

On my Linux system, if I try to type indic characters (specifically Kannada) in gvim (via ibus), the display is so garbled, I can barely see what has been typed. Is it the expected behaviour? Can Gvim display all the utf characters properly like pluma (another editor under Linux) does?

I have avoided asking about vim/neovim supporting these as it would be a terminal issue.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Edit: Attaching a screenshot of the two editors.
[image]

Comment: You might want to include a screenshot to show what you mean... Also potentially relevant: which distro, which version. Version of Gnome/Gtk libraries. What `gvim --version` or the `:version` command says. I think some information about fonts might be relevant too (perhaps `:set gfn?`), but I'm not so sure what other font information might be helpful here... In any case, please add more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem and has been discussed a couple of times in the past. Unfortunately, Vim is not really good suited to the specifics of indic fonts and therefore in the current implementation displays them a bit garbled. Having said that, a PR implementing proper support would certainly be appreciated.

See those threads on the mailinglist: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/25IZ0sMfPbE/oVyhD7vXCwAJ, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/zgzENKfjybA/bB_k9qsh-ysJ and https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/tZV2rBXS_3U/quy6Ovau-BEJ (and most likely there were other threads about it as well).

Comment: Looking at the links, looks like the problem is still unsolved :-( Hope someone knowledgeable in these can solve the problem. If there are any editors with vim like keybindings which show indic characters correctly, that would solve the problem (partly).